# Repeat Groups to form objects

Tags: regex, html-agility-pack

I have a html table like this:

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="country">Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="city">Berlin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="city">Cologne</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="city">Munich</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="country">France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="city">Paris</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td class="country">USA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="city">New York</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

From this table, I want to generate Objects like the classes Country and City. Country would have a List of Cities.

Now to the problem:
It's easy to create a regex to get all countries and all cities, but i wonder if i can get groups for the cities to repeat until the next country starts? I need to do this, because I can't figure out programmatically which city belongs to which country if I have them in seperated regex-matches.

It should be like (quick&dirty solution):

```
country">([\w]*)<{.*\n.*\n.*\n.*"city">([\w]*)}
```

the curly braces should be repeated until the next country item shows up.

If you have a completely different idea on how to get objects out of a html table in c#, let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which formet data you want list ,datatable,var..

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: I don't care about the format. I am using c#, on the html code i don't have any influence.

Comment: you should use an HTML parser

Comment: Allright then, but how can I do this with an html parser? The only idea i had was to split the table at class="country", but I wonder if there is a nicer approach

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: I'm sorry ;) Didn't even realize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree that for any non-trivial HTML a `HTML` parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) should be used. With that said, if your HTML is as simple as the snippet above, this works, even if there are multiple line breaks in the string:

```
string HTML = @"
<table style='width:100%'>
    <tr><td class='country'>Germany</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='city'>Berlin</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='city'>Cologne</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='city'>Munich</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='country'>France</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='city'>Paris</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='country'>USA</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='city'>New York</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='city'>Las Vegas</td></tr>
</table>";

var regex = new Regex(
    @"
        class=[^>]*?
        (?<class>[-\w\d_]+)
        [^>]*>
        (?<text>[^<]+)
        <
    ",
    RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase 
    | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
);

var country = string.Empty;
var Countries = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(HTML))
{
    string countryCity = match.Groups["class"].Value.Trim();
    string text = match.Groups["text"].Value.Trim();
    if (countryCity.Equals("country", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        country = text;
        Countries.Add(text, new List<string>());
    }
    else
    {
        Countries[country].Add(text);
    }
}
```